# Dual Citizen British/US and online business taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, united-kingdom, online-payment, citizenship

I am a dual British/US citizen living in the EU.  I file taxes in the US with my husband.  I want to open an account with an online gallery to sell my artwork and as we intend to retire to UK I will base my business out of the UK.  Do I have to submit my US tax ID to the online gallery or can I be registered as a British artist?  Is it mandatory to use a US tax ID if you have one?

Comment: If the business and its earning are entirely in the UK, you don't have to. However, if you ever do mingle the funds after earning them, make sure that your report it on your tax filing, 1099 style, but you don't have to involve anyone up front.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why a *US* ID would be mandatory anywhere in the *UK*. I'm sure they have their own tax IDs in the UK.

However, if the gallery requires US persons to submit US W-9 - then yes, you're covered under that requirement.

Comment: The website is based in the US.  So I guess I will have to give them my W-9?

Comment: @user15261 very likely.